# How to hide rows on condition from GridView?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

```
   $query =Cms::find();
   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query ,
    ]);
```

Hi, I'm trying to hide certain rows whose 'Status_id' is set to 'Inactive' which is done using a custom action button I've created in the Actions column. I figured I might be able to do it if I could add my own query in the $dataprovider but I don't know how to do that too. Please help if it's the right way and if not how to do I do it? Thanks in advance.Here's my widget.

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        'Contract_id',
        'Status_id',
            ['header' => 'Actions',
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{new_action}',
            'buttons' => [
                'new_action' => function ($url) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Burn Contract'),
                                'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to burn this contract?'),
                                'data-method' => 'post', 'data-pjax' => '0',
                    ]);
                }
            ], 'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model) {
                if ($action === 'new_action') {
                    $url = Url::to(['cms/burn', 'id' => $model->Contract_id]);
                    return $url;
                }
            }
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this may work:

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,

'columns' => [
    'Contract_id',
    'Status_id',
        ['header' => 'Actions',
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{new_action}',
        'buttons' => [
            'new_action' => function ($url) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Burn Contract'),
                            'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to burn this contract?'),
                            'data-method' => 'post', 'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]);
            }
        ], 'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model) {
            if ($action === 'new_action') {
                $url = Url::to(['cms/burn', 'id' => $model->Contract_id,'burn'=>true]);
                return $url;
            }
        }
    ],
],
]);
```

controller:

```
$query =Cms::find();
if (\Yii::$app->request->post('burn')) 
{
    $query->where(['<>','Status_id', 'Inactive']);
}
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'query' => $query
]);
```